# type error: list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer with python for in range

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, typeerror

I am writing a code to count particular text between two texts. This is the code that I have written. When I print(zerg), the result is as follows. I simplified the result for an explanation.

```
wb4 = load_workbook(Gmarket_keyword_file)
ws4 = wb4.active

last_row4 = ws4.max_row

for gs in range(2, last_row4 + 1):
    query = quote(str(ws4.cell(row=gs, column=4).value))
    url = 'https://browse.gmarket.co.kr/search?keyword=' + query
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    zerg = [kr.get_text() for kr in soup.find_all(class_='box__component')] 
    print(zerg)
```

result >>> [아이템카드 먼저 둘러보세요 광고파워클릭 73,230 클럽상품명 남자지갑, 남성지갑, 가죽,지갑 상품명 여성, ...... 아이템카 드골든벨상품명럭셔리, 아이템카드오늘의 상품이에요광고플러스]

I checked two texts as a bold mark. and particular texts as an italic mark. The whole sentence will be changed every time.

This is what I want to do. if Count "상품명" between "먼저 둘러보세요" and "오늘의 상품이에요", the result is 3.

In order to solve this problem, I thought I need to know the index of "먼저 둘러보세요", "오늘의 상품이에요", but these texts are not distinguished in the form of lists. So I coded this as follows.

```
    fi = '먼저'
    zerg_fi = [sp for sp in range(len(zerg)) if fi in zerg[sp]]
    print(zerg_fi)
```

result >> [11]

```
    to = '오늘의'
    zerg_to = [tdp for tdp in range(len(zerg)) if to in zerg[tdp]]
    print(zerg_to)
```

result >> [19]

So, I tried to count the text of '상품명' The codes are as follows.

```
    for zc in range(zerg_fi, zerg_to):
        if zerg.count('상품명') < 5:
            print('수정불필요')
```

But I found an error message. How can I change the codes to solve this error?

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\82103\anaconda3\envs\untitled\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/82103/PycharmProjects/untitled/scraping program/1_crawling practice.py", line 587, in btncmd2
for zc in range(zerg_fi, zerg_to):
```

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: ```range``` parameters are integers. So ```range(len(zerg_fi))``` is correct

Comment: Hold on, what are you trying to do with that last for loop? You make a loop variable `zc` but never use it inside the loop. `zerg.count('상품명') < 5` is going to be the same every iteration, do you really just want to repeatedly print?

Comment: regarding 'range(len(zerg_fi))' can solve the errors. but  "if zerg.count('상품명') < 5" is not working.  In the last loop, I will input as follows. "ws4.cell(row=gs, column=8).value ='수정불필요'. regarding the last loop, I don't know why I don't use zc variable. Is it the reason why the last loop is not working?

Comment: I changed some codes for indentation need to be changed. I think the last loop is a little bit weird because I do not use zc variable. Is there any way to count the number between 'zerg_fi' and 'zerg_fo' and make if - statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list into range() when you should be passing in an int. `Zerg_fi` and `Zerg_to` in the above code are both 1-item lists; to code the equivalent of `range(11,19)`, you need to code `range(Zerg_fi[0], Zerg_to[0])`

Note: if you pass in `Len(Zerg_fi)`, you'd be passing in a value of 1, not 11.

The last for-loop confuses me, but based on your comments, I think this may be the solution if you are trying to check whether `zerg.count('상품명')` is equal to a value between `Zerg_fi[0]` and `Zerg_to[0]`:

```
# test values
zerg_fi = [11]
zerg_to = [19]

zerg = []

# check which is lower zerg_fi or zerg_to 
if zerg_fi[0] < zerg_to[0]:
    for x in range(zerg_fi[0], zerg_to[0]):
        if zerg.count('상품명') == x:
            result = 3
        else:
            # result != 3
            pass
elif zerg_to[0] < zerg_to[0]:
    for x in range(zerg_to[0], zerg_fi[0]):
        if zerg.count('상품명') == x:
            result = 3
        else:
            # result != 3
            pass
# 'else' will execute if zerg_fi[0]==zerg_to[0]
else:
    x = zerg_fi[0]
    if zerg.count('상품명') == x:
        # result = 3 ? .... not sure if you want this
        pass
    else:
        # result != 3 ? ... not sure if you want this
```

I wasn't sure if `Zerg_to[0]` could ever be less than `Zerg_fi[0]` (or honestly whether that even matters for `range()`), but in case it does, I included the if/else statement to handle that.